# Gap between objects (images) in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on a clicker game, which implies the interaction of 2 players. One of the objects (images made with ui) becomes larger if one of the players taps more. But I ran into a problem, for some reason unity creates a gap between objects. Also, if the red object becomes larger than blue - the problem disappears. I have attached the code and video with the problem.
The problem isn't in random values.
Also i tried to fix it with Transform.SetSiblingIndex, and it didn't work either.

[There's a link to screenshot with the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9kpu.png)

[there's a link to video with the problem](https://youtu.be/qDwQVjKt_6g)

The code from GameCore:

```
public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    ScaleEvents();
    Vector3 clickPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(eventData.position);
    if (eventData.rawPointerPress == Player1)
    {
        Player1.transform.localScale += scaleChange;
        Player2.transform.localScale -= scaleChange;
    }
    else if(eventData.rawPointerPress == Player2)
    {
        Player2.transform.localScale += scaleChange;
        Player1.transform.localScale -= scaleChange;
        Player1.transform.SetSiblingIndex(0);
    }
    Debug.Log(clickPosition);
    Debug.Log(eventData.rawPointerPress);
    Debug.Log(randomScaleChange);
}

private void ScaleEvents()
{
    randomScaleChange = Random.Range(0.05f, 0.3f);
    scaleChange = new Vector3(0.0f, randomScaleChange, 0f);

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's what a code looks like now and still didn't work:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class ClickerZone : MonoBehaviour, IPointerClickHandler
{
[SerializeField] private GameObject _Player1;
[SerializeField] private GameObject _Player2;
private RectTransform _player1Rect;
private RectTransform _player2Rect;
private Vector3 _scaleChange;
private float _randomScaleChange;


private void Awake()
{
    _player1Rect = _Player1.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
    _player2Rect = _Player2.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
}

public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    ScaleEvents();
    Vector3 clickPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(eventData.position);
    if (eventData.rawPointerPress == _Player1)
    {
        _Player1.transform.localScale += _scaleChange;
        _player1Rect.sizeDelta = new Vector2(0f, _player1Rect.sizeDelta.y + _randomScaleChange);
        _Player2.transform.localScale -= _scaleChange;
        _player2Rect.sizeDelta = new Vector2(0f, _player2Rect.sizeDelta.y - _randomScaleChange);

    }
    else if(eventData.rawPointerPress == _Player2)
    {
        _Player2.transform.localScale += _scaleChange;
        _player2Rect.sizeDelta = new Vector2(0f, _player2Rect.sizeDelta.y + _randomScaleChange);
        _Player1.transform.localScale -= _scaleChange;
        _player1Rect.sizeDelta = new Vector2(0f, _player1Rect.sizeDelta.y - _randomScaleChange);
    }
    Debug.Log(clickPosition);
    Debug.Log(eventData.rawPointerPress);
    Debug.Log(_randomScaleChange);
}

private void ScaleEvents()
{
    _randomScaleChange = Random.Range(0.05f, 0.3f);
    _scaleChange = new Vector3(0.0f, _randomScaleChange, 0f);
}
}
```

Comment: You still try to change the scale of your GameObjects. Please look closely at my code example that I provided above. You should not use `localScale` at all.

Comment: Also note that you'll need to roll bigger random numbers when manipulating the height of your RectTransforms. Rather roll numbers between 5 and 30, instead of 0.05 and 0.3.

Comment: Holy crap, you are genius, it's finally worked, thank you so much <3

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, should you rather use `RectTransform.deltaSize.y`, and adjust the actual height of your UI elements, instead of the scale. Someone smarter than me can explain to you why. If I tried to explain it, I would probably cause more confusion.

Your blue element should be anchored to the top, and your red element should be anchored to the bottom. If you now add 50 pixel to the height of your blue element, and substract 50 from the height of your red element, it should work out, without a gap in between.

Also, please note that with your current solution, your red bar grows bigger than the amount of which your blue bar shrinks. So yes, you don't have a gap. But your Red bar is actually overdrawing over your blue bar.

---

Edit:

Below I present you a possible solution that hopefully gets you on the right track.
For it to work, blue needs to be anchored to the top of your screen. **Anchors Min: 0, 1**; **Max; 1, 1**; **Pivot 0.5, 1**.

Red needs to be anchored to the bottom of the screen. **Anchors Min: 0,0**; **Max; 1, 0**; **Pivot 0.5, 0**.
Set the hight for both elements so that they touch seamlessly.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class ClickGame : MonoBehaviour, IPointerClickHandler
{
    public RectTransform Player1;
    public RectTransform Player2;
    float randomScaleChange;

    public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        ScaleEvents();
        Vector3 clickPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(eventData.position);

        if (clickPosition.y > 0f) // Blue clicked
        {
            Player1.sizeDelta = new Vector2(100f, Player1.sizeDelta.y + randomScaleChange);
            Player2.sizeDelta = new Vector2(100f, Player2.sizeDelta.y - randomScaleChange);

        }

        if (clickPosition.y < 0f) // Red clicked
        {
            Player2.sizeDelta = new Vector2(100f, Player2.sizeDelta.y + randomScaleChange);
            Player1.sizeDelta = new Vector2(100f, Player1.sizeDelta.y - randomScaleChange);
        }
    }

    private void ScaleEvents()
    {
        randomScaleChange = Random.Range(5f, 50f);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think I did what you said, but it still didn't work :/

Comment: Can you be more specific? What does not work? I tested my code with the anchor settings as I described them, and it works fine on my end.